# Derivative is Zero on a dense G_delta set

Tags: real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory, differential-calculus

I have the following question:
I have a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which is differentiable everywhere.
I also have a set $G\subset\mathbb R$ which is dense in $\mathbb R$ and a $G_\delta$-set.
I know that $f'(x)=0 \forall x\in G$.

Can I conclude that $f$ is constant?

The answer is yes if $f'$ is continuous, but unfortunately I don't know that.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the zero set is always a $G_\delta$, the question is whether it being dense implies that the function is constant. This is false, and a counterexample is known as a [Pompeiu derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative).

Comment: This function is not however differentiable everywhere, contrary to the assumption in the question. I suspect the question was just misstated though since it doesn't seem to be interesting if you assume that.

Comment: @R.. The first sentence of the link says that it's a derivative of an everywhere differentiable function.

Comment: The WP article is sloppy; it says the derivative at some points "$=+\infty$" and papers over what that means. Maybe there are senses in which it makes sense to call this everywhere-differentiable anyway, but I would call it ae-differentiable.

Comment: The function they actually take in the end is the inverse of that one, which has finite derivative everywhere.

Comment: @R if you read more carefully, $g(x)$ is the *inverse* of a function $f$ with finite derivative at every point, and $f'(x)=0$ iff $g'(f(x))=+\infty$. Of course "derivative" here has the usual meaning of limit of the incremental ratio in the extended real line. Quite a nice and well-written article, indeed.